# How do I prove this sequence is always smaller than this following limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How do I prove this sequence, which I found is monotonic and rising

$ a_{1} = 1, a_{n+1} = \sqrt{c+da_{n}}$
 while             $d,c >1 $

is always smaller than the suspicious limit I found to it $L = \frac{d+ \sqrt{d^2+4c}}{2}$

tried induction but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you already know that $a_n$ is monotonic increasing then $a_{n-1}<a_n$ and:

$$a_n^2=c+da_{n-1}<c+da_n \rightarrow a_n^2-da_n-c<0\rightarrow \frac{d-\sqrt{d^2+4c}}{2}<a_n<\frac{d+\sqrt{d^2+4c}}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{c+dx}$ for $x\geq 1$.

$f'(x)=\frac{d}{2f(x)}>0$
$f$ is strictly increasing at $[1,+\infty)$.

$L=\frac{d+\sqrt{d^2+4c}}{2}>1$ is a fixed point of $f$.

by induction , it is easy to prove that $\forall n>0 \; a_n<L$.

- $a_1=1<L$
- $a_n<L\implies a_{n+1}=f(a_n)<f(L)=L$

Comment: Sorry didn't understand the last two lines especially the third, what do you mean by L>1 is a fixed point of f, and to which L are you referring to when you talk about induction, the one I gave or the L>1 ?

Comment: @user3575645 I edited a new answer.